# IoT Analytics dataset contains only __dt. Is my query broken?

Tags: aws-iot-analytics

I've been beating my head against this for a while.  I have created a channel, pipeline, datastore and dataset, but the dataset just contains __dt no matter what I do.

I believe the channel, pipeline, and datastore are working, primarily because I see correctly formatted JSON messages in the S3 bucket for the datastore.

My datastore is called "salt_datastore".  When I navigate to the relevant S3 bucket, I see a folder called "salt_datastore", and in it, I see a folder with today's date called "__dt=2022-10-09 00:00:00/".  Inside that folder, I see a separate .gz file for every message I have sent, with names of the format "1665276480000_1665276510000_435011638936_salt_sensor_0_840.0.salt_sensor_pipeline.json.gz".  If I download and open one of these, I see the MQTT messages that were sent to the MQTT topic.

So I think the channel, pipeline, and datastore are working, but if I set up a dataset with the query "select * from salt_datastore", I only get "__dt".  I feel like this is the starting text of the folder inside the salt_datastore S3 bucket, but I can't figure out how to construct a valid SQL query that gives me what's inside that folder.  Any help?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

```
DELETED INCORRECT ANSWER
```

## Edited

Previously I incorrectly said to put the name of the datastore in single quotes in the sql query.

But it was the name of the topic that I had to put in single quotes. This is actually in your sql statement in the IoT Core rule

**NOT**

the sql statement for the datastore.

So the sql for the topic should look like

```
SELECT * FROM 'some_topic'
```

That is, the topic that that you are publishing to.

## Adding query images

### Topic query

[image: Topic Query]

### Dataset query

[image: Dataset Query]

Comment: When I try that I get a red popup message that says "We could not update your data set.  Provided SQL query is malformed."  Using double quotes around "salt_datastore" doesn't have the same error, but it also doesn't appear to work any differently, showing just __dt in the dataset.

Comment: Apologies, I had posted an incorrect solution before. I have updated the answer to the reflect what I had actually done to fix the issue for me.

Comment: I had been away from this for a long time, but your response got me looking at it again.  I started all over and created a new channel, datastore, and dataset with the Quick Start, and it works fine now - my dataset is filling up.  I compared my non-functional instances to the Quick Start ones, and the main difference I see is that the datastore storage is managed by the service.  In my previous datastore, the storage was an S3 bucket managed by me.  I suspect that maybe there was some disconnect there.  It seemed like the data was making it into the bucket, but something wasn't working right.

Comment: Hey, good going!